# How to set {{platform}} in ionic framework?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm using ionic/AngularJS to create a mobile app. I've seen a {{platform}} template attribute on this page: http://ionicframework.com/docs/angularjs/controllers/view-state/

How can I set this globally when I'm testing using `python -mSimpleHTTPServer` instead of an emulator?

Answer (score 4):

It's as simple as :

```
ionic.Platform.setPlatform('android')
ionic.Platform.platform() // "android"
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like the docs are wrong (outdated?).
anyway - the "platform" value is available at

> ionic.Platform.platform

See ionic.js:2085